# Disconnect object from NHibernate session

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In my nhibenate session I Mapping object with AutoMapper and in the afterMap action i create new instance of the object because I extract the object from the DB for properties compare.
So The AutoMapper create two instances of one object with the same ID.
When I try to commit the session i get error that i have to object with the same ID.

So I Want to disconnect the object that I extract  after the properties compare.
After that I will can commit the session

How I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

You can use `session.Evict(persistentObject)` to evict a persistent object from the session. This will remove the object from the 1st level cache, thus allowing you to flush the session.

Comment: Is it possible to remove it from all sessions?

Comment: Unless you do something really really funky, your objects will be connected to at most one session: the one that hydrated it

Comment: I really wish that was true. I've some legacy code that does funkier stuff, so I came across this exception, and I hoped there would be some hackish workaround, but oh well...